# How to concatenate all strings of an array in Minizinc?

Tags: arrays, string, optimization, concatenation, minizinc

In minizinc you can use an aggregation function like 'sum' to sum all items in an array. For instance:

```
array[0..10] of par int:price = array1d(0..10,[0,1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]);
sum (i in 0..10) (price[i]); %Aggregation function
```

Is there a way to concatenate all strings of an array in a similar way?
For instance something like the following:

```
array[0..29] of par string: symbols=array1d(SYMBOLS_SIZE,["A" , "B" , "C" , "D" , "E" , "F" , "G" , "H" , "I" , "J" , "K"]; 
concatenate(i in 0..10) (symbols[i]); %Aggregation function for Strings
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that there is actually a builtin function called concat.

```
function string: concat(array [$T] of string: s)
```

The function return concatenation of strings in array s.  [Minizinc Reference](https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.3.1/en/lib-builtins.html#string-operations)

So what I was looking for was just:

```
array[0..29] of par string: symbols=array1d(SYMBOLS_SIZE,["A" , "B" , "C" , "D" , "E" , "F" , "G" , "H" , "I" , "J" , "K"]; 
concat(i in 0..10) (symbols[i]); %Aggregation function for Strings
```